# how to use helper class to send and receive data using intent in android

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqpJt.png)
I want to fetch the data from previous activity (using getIntent) in a .java class and same the data to next activity through intent. can anyone help me how.Thanks in advance.

```
public class AddToCartHelper {

    public static void addToCart(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String TAG = "AddToCart";
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat;
        boolean loginflagforuser = false, loginflagforguest = false;

        String advId = "", num = "", uid = "", productName = "", emailCart = "",cartMessage = "";
        Double price = 0.0;
        Integer quantity = 1;

        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("SECRETFILE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        loginflagforuser = preferences.getBoolean(Parameters.userEmail, false);
        loginflagforguest = preferences.getBoolean(Parameters.guestEmail, false);
        decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("##.##");

        if (loginflagforuser){

            Intent fromCart = getIntent();
            //    imageId = fromCart.getStringExtra("image_url");
            advId = fromCart.getStringExtra("Advid");
            price = fromCart.getDoubleExtra("price", 0.0);
            num = fromCart.getStringExtra("num");
            uid = fromCart.getStringExtra("uid");
            Log.d(TAG, "--- REGISTERD UID::::::::: " + uid);
            quantity = fromCart.getIntExtra("quantity", 1);
            productName = fromCart.getStringExtra("cart_product_name");
            // total = fromCart.getDoubleExtra("total", 0.0);

            emailCart = preferences.getString("email", null);

        }else if (loginflagforguest){

        }else{

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: so you already can  get data from previous activity?

Comment: No I'm unable to get data. when i try getIntent(). It is throwing an error.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @GGanesh Can you show that error?

Comment: sent the sceenshot. please check

Comment: getIntent() cannot be called on nonactivity class. Capture the Intent first on your Activity class and send it to your nonactivity class.

Comment: You already declare  the `Intent intent` as parameters in your addToCart methods but based on your code you didn' even use it. once you supply the correct intent on your method you can just directly call `advId = intent.getStringExtra("Advid");` without calling getIntent().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already pass parameter `intent` to addToCart function, so instead of `advId = fromCart.getStringExtra("Advid");`, you can use `advId = intent.getStringExtra("Advid");`

Comment: How to pass data from same java class to other Activity.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to use this Intent fromCart = getIntent();,because in constructor you already pass intent ,then just use intent object

```
dvId = intent.getStringExtra("Advid");
            price = intent.getDoubleExtra("price", 0.0);
            num = intent.getStringExtra("num");
            uid = intent.getStringExtra("uid");
            Log.d(TAG, "--- REGISTERD UID::::::::: " + uid);
            quantity = intent.getIntExtra("quantity", 1);
            productName = intent.getStringExtra("cart_product_name");
            // total = intent.getDoubleExtra("total", 0.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is two ways to passing the data to the next activity you can either use intent or can use local broadcast receiver

if you want to fetch data from the previous activity then use

```
String a= getIntent().getStringExtra( "");// pass the name that you used in the previous activity
```

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: I want to fetch data to a class not to activity. Activity -> .java class. ->Activity. Data passing and fetching should be done by a normal java class.